# App development on topic?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

Just wanted to check whether or not Android App development questions were on topic here?

Comment: Glad, to find that you asked your query here rather than posting straight as a new user and then finding out, Oops! wrong place. // Just a note: some queries can be solved without even bothering to ask here by taking a look at [help] of the particular network site. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned on the Help Center page titled "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)":

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - **Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on
>     Stack Overflow)**
> - Marketing your Android app or doing market research
> - Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher
> - Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and where to buy it
> - Speculative questions, like "When will X be available in my country?" or "Why does Company X do this?"
> - Legal questions, such as "Will X void my warranty?"
> - Android-independent questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"

Comment: Ask a question - receive an answer. Thanks very much :)